# Ecto faking migrations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

What's the best way to fake a migration? I have big database table where I need to remove duplicates and in the same transaction add unique index. This is the safest and easiest way to resolve this issue. But when this is done my tests start to fail. There is no mention of unique index in migrations. So when I'm testing for unique constraint it just fails.

I think the best way to solve this issue is to create a fake migration. Migration that would not do anything just add unique index for the tests. I could remove test for unique but I don't like that approach. That would also not solve inconsistency between test and production database.

Comment: You should split your data migrations from your structure migrations, and run the data migrations on your chosen environment databases.

Answer (score 0):

Is your index set to be `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`

Your test will then fail as it runs in a sandbox (single transaction) so it wont trigger the contraint.

You can get around it by running

```
Repo.query!("SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE", [])
```

at the start of your test.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to be "faking" migrations.  Your database structure should be uniform throughout the variety of environments.  If you don't have this security, your tests are unreliable and do more harm than good.

Without knowing what tests are actually failing, it's hard to say what the exact issue is, but you mentioned:

> So when I'm testing for unique constraint it just fails.

To me, I think this means that the testing suite does not have the same migration head or just database structure in general, both databases should be reading the same index's and you do not want to have the structure changing between environments.

I would drop the TESTING database and create/migrate the data structure.  Keep in mind that if you want to do this you'll need to wrap any migration code that expects the database to have data in it with something like:

```
unless Mix.env() in [:test] do
   # code expecting data to be in database
end
```

This way your testing suite will have the same structure as the other environments and you won't have issues with grabbing data from an empty database.